# Facebook Canvas Application Does Not Load <body>

Tags: facebook, debugging, heroku, facebook-canvas

My question is almost identical to the one found here: [Facebook canvas application never loads <body> contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305252/facebook-canvas-application-never-loads-body-contents)

However I'm running flask through Heroku's cedar stack. My url has always been the heroku subdomain so the solution above does not apply. Most of the time the application never loads past the head tags. Has anyone made any progress on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've found is that the post to Heroku is not asking for all the required bytes.  Here is what my POST looks like from Heroku logs:

2012-07-06T02:33:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.191.221.194 - - [06/Jul/2012 02:33:33] "POST /?fb_source=search&ref=ts HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2012-07-06T02:33:33+00:00 heroku[router]: POST simple-frost-5348.herokuapp.com/?fb_source=search&ref=ts dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3040ms status=200 **bytes=2757**

You'll see it is asking for 2757 bytes, which is exactly where the truncation occurs in my app.

It happens only after you log in and connect with the FB app.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This is happening to me persistently and I have no idea how to fix it?